# how to create a dictionary with one index key column and multiple value columns

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe df with 3 columns A,B,C. I want column A to be the index and key and columns B and C as A's values.

I have tried the below:

```
def cellDict():

    df_set_index('A')['B','C']
    x= df.set_index('A')['B']
    y= df.set_index('A')['C']
    z= zip(x,y)


def getCellDetails():
    try:
        cellDB_DF= pd.read_excel('cell_DB.xlsx')
        cellLatDB= cellDB_DF['Latitude'].to_dict()
        cellLongDB= cellDB_DF['Longitude'].to_dict()
        cellDict= cellDF.set_index('Cell_ID')['Latitude']['Longitude'].to_dict()
        print cellDict

    except Exception as e:
        print e.message
```

The excepted result would be like

```
df{cellID}=('latitude','longitude')
```

Comment: First initialize, mydict = dict() and then just build a loop logic: for <values in pandas df>: mydict[cellID] = (x, y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [100, 200, 300], 'C': [400, 500, 600]})
>>> df
   A    B    C
0  1  100  400
1  2  200  500
2  3  300  600
```

Then use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {key: (a, b) for key, a, b in df.values}
{1: (100, 400), 2: (200, 500), 3: (300, 600)}
```

Per the recommendation of @piRSquared, you could also transpose the dataframe and then use the `to_dict` function specifying `list` as the orientation variable.

```
df.set_index('A').T.to_dict('list')
```

His other recommendation provides a very efficient solution:

```
dict(zip(df.A, zip(df.B, df.C)))
```

**Timings** *(Python 3.7 with pandas 0.24.2)*

```
# Set-up 10k row dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10000), 'B': range(10000), 'C': range(10000)})

# Method 1
%timeit -n 10 {key: (a, b) for key, a, b in df.values}
# 14.8 ms ± 3.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Method 2
%timeit -n 10 df.set_index('A').T.to_dict('list')
# 520 ms ± 41.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Method 3
%timeit -n 10 dict(zip(df.A, zip(df.B, df.C)))
# 7.7 ms ± 3.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Method 4
%timeit -n 10 {k: (a, b) for k, a, b in zip(*map(df.get, df))}
# 9.61 ms ± 3.81 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: On my phone so I cannot verify my answers  “dict(zip(df.A, zip(df.B, df.C)))”. Or “df.set_index(‘A’).T.to_dict(‘list’)”

Comment: @piRSquared Both of your solutions work. The first one is very efficient (Method 3) the second one appears to be rather slow (Method 2). I am testing using Python 3.7.3 and pandas 0.24.2.

Comment: I suspect this should speed up yours: “{k: (a, b) for k, a, b in zip(*map(df.get, df))}”